# AppEngine + GWT-RPC + Search API giving error

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-platform

Appengine - 1.9.63

GWT - 2.8.1

Client to Server Side Call: Using Standard GWT RPC Implementation

Server Side Code:

```
IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("index").build(); 
Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(indexSpec);
Document doc = Document.newBuilder()...
try{
    index.put(doc); //Line that results in an exception
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Stacktrace:

com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: **Can't make API call search.IndexDocument in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager**
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:800)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:175)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$1.get(ApiProxy.java:172)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:73)
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
    at com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexImpl.put(IndexImpl.java:485)
    at com.vehicle.track.server.User.save(User.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

With the App Engine Java8 Runtime Environment you can create threads using App Engine's [ThreadManager API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager) and Java's built-in APIs, for example `new Thread()`. However, as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#threads):

> Currently, if you want to call App Engine APIs
>   (com.google.appengine.api.*), you must call those APIs from a request
>   thread or from a thread created using the ThreadManager API.

I can see in your Stacktrace that you indeed use a background thread via threadpool. You'll need to implement it using the ThreadManager API.

Comment: I specifically didn't implement any background thread in my client or server side implementation. Does this have anything to do with GWT RPC based server communication? If yes, what's the workaround? Can you share some code?